# Double checked locking lazy Initialization - Do I need to have volatile keyword for the Map

Tags: java

From [Usage_in_Java & *Effective Java 2*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java), I do understand I need to have `volatile` keyword, if the lazy initialization target is a single variable.

However, what about I'm perform multiple lazy initialization, and store them in a `ConcurrentHashMap`? Does the `Map` need to be volatile too?

Here's the code example.

```
public class Utils {
    private static final Map<Integer, RemoteViews> remoteViewsMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, RemoteViews>();

    public static RemoteViews getRemoteViews(int resourceId) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = remoteViewsMap.get(resourceId);
        if (remoteViews == null) {
            synchronized(remoteViewsMap){
                remoteViews = remoteViewsMap.get(resourceId);
                if (remoteViews == null) {
                    remoteViews = new RemoteViews("org.yccheok.gui", resourceId);
                    remoteViewsMap.put(resourceId, remoteViews);
                }
            }
        }
        return remoteViews;
    }
}
```

Is the above code correct and thread safe?

Comment: No, it is final, so it not need to be volatile. I think this is not threadsafe though (it depends what you want to achieve), other threads can put the same resourceId in the remoiteViewsMap during the getRemoteViews while waiting for the lock..

Comment: This isn't double-checked - you have to check both inside and outside the synchronized

Comment: @Eric Thanks. I miss out the checking. I rectify my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for `volatile` keyword since `ConcurrentHashMap` being an implementation of `ConcurrentMap` provides the following memory consistency effect:

> actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a ConcurrentMap as a key or value happen-before actions subsequent to the access or removal of that object from the ConcurrentMap in another thread

However, that's not how you usually want to work with concurrent map. General pattern is as follows:

```
Object existing = concurrentMap.get(key);
// check if this key is already present
if (existing == null) {
  Object newObject = new Object();
  existing = concurrentMap.putIfAbsent(key, newObject); // atomic operation
  // another thread might have already stored mapping for key
  if (existing == null) {
    return newObject;
  }
}
return existing;
```

Note, it doesn't protect you from two threads simultaneously calling `new Object()` (which can be an issue if creation of new object is expensive), but it allows you to avoid explicit synchronization alltogether.

Update: as for double-checked locking, in your case, it should look as follows:

```
Object value = concurrentMap.get(key);
if (value == null) {
  synchronized (lock) {
    value = concurrentMap.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
      value = new Object();
      concurrentMap.put(key, value);
    }
  }
}
return value;
```

Comment: Since I want to avoid unnecessary "double" construction on my RemoteViews, I don't not use `putIfAbsent` technique. Any way, is the synchronized technique thread safe?

Comment: In this case you need to employ double-checked locking (which you don't, since you don't double-check if mapping is already present under lock), as others have already mentioned in comments.

Comment: You're missing an assignment in second `if` clause. Your code will return `null` if it gets there. See update of my answer.

Comment: Is it? I thought I do have assignment in second `if` clause after I rectify my code?

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're right, I didn't notice it. The code looks OK now.